# Java Interface Generics argument

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

```
public void inputData(Scanner input, List<E> productList) {
    System.out.println("Please input the product ID:");
    do {
        this.productId = input.nextLine();
        boolean checkId = false;
        if (this.productId.startsWith("P") && this.productId.length() == 5) {
            if (productList.size() == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
                    if (this.productId.equals(productList.get(i).getProductId())) {
                        System.err.println("The inputted ID is already existed. Please try another!");
                        checkId = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!checkId) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Please input the correct format of product ID(exp: P****)!");
        }
    } while (true);
```

I created an inteface class IShop and the classes Product and Categories implements Ishop. I would like to use generics type to pass method's parameters.
Please help me to explain why I cannot access getProductId() in this case.

Comment: What is `E`? Also, kind of weird that product and categories implement shop - I would have thought a shop contained products grouped by categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code snippet you have provided, it looks like you are applying **Generics** without a proper idea.

In this code, you need to ensure that the type you're using supports the methods you want to call. In your case, you're trying to call the `getProductId()` method on elements in a `List<E> productList`, where `E` is a generic type parameter. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know for sure what methods `E` supports because it's a generic placeholder.

You can try in this way:

Ensure that the type `E` used in the `List<E> productList` actually has a method named `getProductId()`. You can specify a bound on the generic type parameter when defining your interface or class.
(if your `Product` class has a `getProductId()` method, you can define your interface `IShop` with a generic type parameter that extends `Product`)

```
public interface IShop<E extends Product> {
    void inputData(Scanner input, List<E> productList);
}
```

Likewise, when implementing the `IShop` interface in your Product and Categories classes, you need to specify the type argument for `E`.

```
public class Product implements IShop<Product> {
    // your logic
}
```